# How to have the rolling distinct count of each day for past three days in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I searched for this a lot, but I couldn't find the solution yet. let me explain my question by sample data and my desired output. 
sample data:

```
datetime           customer
----------         --------
2018-10-21 09:00   Ryan
2018-10-21 10:00   Sarah
2018-10-21 20:00   Sarah
2018-10-22 09:00   Peter
2018-10-22 10:00   Andy
2018-10-23 09:00   Sarah
2018-10-23 10:00   Peter
2018-10-24 10:00   Andy
2018-10-24 20:00   Andy
```

my desired output is to have the distinctive number of customers for past three days relative to each day:

```
trunc(datetime)   progressive count distinct customer
---------------   -----------------------------------
2018-10-21         2
2018-10-22         4
2018-10-23         4
2018-10-24         3
```

explanation: for 21th, because we have only Ryan and Sarah the count is 2 (also because we have no other records before 21th); for 22th Andy and Peter are added to the distinct list, so it's 4. for 23th, no new customer is added so it would be 4. for 24th, however, as we only should consider past 3 days (as per business logic), we should only take 24th,23th and 22th; so the distinct customers would be Sarah, Andy and Peter. so the count is 3.

I believe it is called the progressive count, or moving count or rolling up count. but I couldn't implement it in Oracle 11g SQL. Obviously it's easy by using PL-SQL programming (Stored-Procedure/Function). but, preferably I wonder if we can have it by a single SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to want is:

```
select date,
       count(distinct customer) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row)
from (select distinct trunc(datetime) as date, customer
      from t
     ) t
group by date;
```

However, Oracle does not support window frames with `count(distinct)`.

One rather brute force approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select date,
       (select count(distinct t2.customer)
        from t t2
        where t2.datetime >= t.date - 2
       ) as running_3
from (select distinct trunc(datetime) as date
      from t
     ) t;
```

This should have reasonable performance for a small number of dates.  As the number of dates increases, the performance will degrade linearly.